# switch case like selection in LINQ-C#

Tags: c#, linq

**How can i apply switch..case like selection in LINQ ?**

choice between this and this  select this end

choice between this and this  select this end

...

...

choice between this and this  select this end

choice between this and this  select this end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple example:

```
bool showEven = false;
var query = Enumerable.Range(0, 100);

switch (showEven)
{
    case true: query = query.Where(i => i % 2 == 0); break;
    case false: query = query.Where(i => i % 2 == 1); break;
}

foreach (var item in query)
    Console.WriteLine(item);
```